# OpenAM change url

Tags: web, dns, alias, openam, forgerock

I have installed my openam at this addres for example: http://openam-virtualmachine.mydomain.com:8080/openam

I my DNS i have associated openam-virtualmachine.mydomain at this alias: topolino

Now I want to reach my openam using this address: http://topolino:8080/openam but it doesn't works.

There are any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do: do you want to access AM only on topolino, or on the long FQDN as well?

Comment: @PeterMajor Could you explain me the two possible way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have mapped topoline with openam-virtualmachine.mydomain, then you should add both the FQDNs in the DNS alias present under Top Level Realm-> Properties. Here we mention all the DNS through which requests are to be mapped.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, you need to add `topolino` as a **cookie domain**, by going to `Configuration -> System -> Platform`